# MySQL permutations of single list

Tags: mysql, relational-database, permutation

Bit of a database newbie here. I have a table list this:

```
author_id   book_id(PK)   book_title   other_book_info
======================================================
1           1             Grass        etc.
1           2             Fire         etc.
2           3             Green        etc.
2           4             Red          etc.
```

I'm interested in matching all books from Author1 with all books from Author2 with some correlation called book_similarity (outside the scope of the question). What's the best practice way of creating a table of all permutations like this?:

```
sim_id(PK)   book_id1    book_id2     book_similarity
=====================================================
1            1           3            High
2            1           4            Low
3            2           3            Low
4            2           4            High
```

Book similarity is commutative (ie. matching **1 vs. 3** is the same as **3 vs. 1**) so I only need the permutations of book titles, not the combinations.

However, I suspect that it would be best practice to create a longer table with all combinations that has 16 rows so that if I'm looking for a particular book (say #4), that I only need to look in book_id1 rather than book_id1 and book_id2. What's the consensus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do a `cross join` and select the particular authors you want:

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as id, b1.book_id as book_id1, b2.book_id as book_id2,
       YOURSIMILARITYFUNCTIONHERE
from books b1 cross join
     books b2 cross join
     (select @rn := 0) vars
where b1.author_id = 1 and b2.author_id = 2;
```

Without the `where`, this will choose all pairwise combinations.

Comment: Thanks - this is really useful. I think I will end up using `WHERE b1.author_id != b2.author_id`. This gives me cross-comparisons with all the books I need, and a full lookup column (book_id2) which has every book entry in.